# orientDB traverse really slow

Tags: orientdb

I have some serious performance problems using orientdb. 
I have got a plocal graph Database with a sheme like the following, the data is imported from JSON:

```
PersonA --hasInterest-> InterestA
PersonA --hasInterest-> InterestB
PersonB --hasInterest-> InterestA
PersonB --hasInterest-> InterestB
```

My goal is to find Interests that occur in combination with a given Interest. So my query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( TRAVERSE out_hasInterest FROM ( SELECT FROM ( TRAVERSE in_hasInterest FROM #12:33 ) WHERE $depth > 0 )) WHERE $depth > 0
```

Where #12:33 is an Interest.

My real data is a bit bigger than this small snippet so for a concrete Interest there are ~500,000 Persons associated which have an average of ~3 Interests. So I would Traverse 500,000 + 500,000 * 3 = 2,000,000 Vertices. That seems not to be that much.

The query needs ~100 seconds. This is far to much for my application.

I think I am doing something terribly wrong, I can't believe the performance is that bad.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards
Ludwig

---

*Version: 1.7-rc1*

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using traverse? If I understand correctly your goal you could do:

```
SELECT expand( in('hasInterest').out('hasInterest') ) FROM #12:33
```

Comment: Hey Lvca, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but the query ran about half an hour before i killed it.

Why is traverse the wrong way to go ? Should I use traverse only if I dont know how long my path is ?

Comment: thanks for your answer Lvca I will give the snapshot a try. But I still can't believe that the performance of 1.7-rc1 should be that bad.

Comment: Depends by many settings. For example the cache: Do you have enabled level1 (and even 2) caches?

Comment: OrientDB is now many times faster than it was in 2014, please try again using Lvca's query.